# split the string through regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a string like this

```
[website name] VARCHAR(50), [affiliate name] VARCHAR(128), [dynamite data lid]  VARCHAR(50),
```

I want to split this using regular expression in C# to

```
website name
VARCHAR(50)
affiliate name
VARCHAR(128)
dynamite data lid
VARCHAR(50)
```

I don't want extra line at starting of my solution

Comment: where's the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Match All instead of Splitting**

Use this regex:

```
(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\])|\S+(?=,)
```

In C#:

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
try {
    Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\])|\S+(?=,|$)");
    Match matchResult = myRegex.Match(yourString);
    while (matchResult.Success) {
        resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
        matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `\[([\w\s]+)\]\s+(\w+\(\d+\))` That will match and capture the components into groups that you can then use.